How to Get the Selected File Path from a File Dialog in Windows Using Python?
To implement a file preview feature similar to Quick Look on Windows, there are a few existing tools, each with their own issues:

QuickLook: Slow file preview, occasional crashes, and lack of maintenance.

Seer: Fast file preview, occasional crashes, paid software without a one-time purchase option.

Peek in PowerToys: Very slow file preview, unnatural operation logic, and limited file type support.


Therefore, I plan to develop a new software for Windows, using Python, based on the technologies I'm familiar with.
Initial Idea

After the software starts, it runs a daemon process that listens for hotkeys (e.g., the spacebar). Additionally, it can open a settings window and initialize an invisible preview window.

When the hotkey is pressed, the program checks whether the window in the foreground is the system desktop, file explorer, or file dialog, and then retrieves the selected file's path.

Based on the file path and its type, the program previews the file (plain text, folder, compressed file, audio/video file, etc.) and displays the result in the preview window.


Initial Implementation
from contextlib import contextmanager
from time import time

import pythoncom
import pywintypes
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow, GetClassName


@contextmanager
def com_context():
    """
    Use context manager to handle COM (Component Object Model) initialization and uninitialization.
    """
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()


def get_path_from_explorer(hwnd: int) -> str:
    with com_context():
        shell = Dispatch("Shell.Application")
        windows = shell.Windows()
        for window in windows:
            try:
                if window.HWND == hwnd:
                    paths = [item.Path for item in window.Document.SelectedItems()]
                    return paths[0] if paths else ''
            except pywintypes.com_error:
                continue
        return ''


def get_path_from_desktop() -> str:
    with com_context():
        shell = Dispatch("Shell.Application")
        desktop_folder = shell.Windows().Item()
        if desktop_folder is not None and desktop_folder.Document:
            paths = [item.Path for item in desktop_folder.Document.SelectedItems()]
            return paths[0] if paths else ''
        return ''


def get_path_from_file_dialog(hwnd) -> str:
    ...  # Implementation needed


class Activator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeout = 0.2  # Timeout considered as 200 ms
        self.holding = 0.0
        self.handle_key = Key.space
        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(self._press_key, self._release_key)
        self.path = ''

    def activate(self):
        self.listener.start()
        print('Keyboard listener started...')
        self.listener.join()

    def _press_key(self, key: Key | KeyCode | None) -> None:
        self.path = self.get_path()
        if key == self.handle_key and self.path:
            self.holding = time() if self.holding == 0.00 else self.holding

    def _release_key(self, key: Key | KeyCode | None) -> None:
        if key == self.handle_key:
            is_fleeting: bool = time() - self.holding < self.timeout
            ...
            print(f'{"Valid" if is_fleeting else "Invalid"} space key press and release')
            print(self.path)
            self.holding = 0.0

    @staticmethod
    def get_path() -> str:
        """Determine the file path based on the window class name of the foreground window"""
        hwnd: int = GetForegroundWindow()
        assert hwnd != 0, 'System idle, no active window, screensaver state, or insufficient permissions'

        window_class_name = GetClassName(hwnd)
        match window_class_name:
            case 'CabinetWClass':  # File Explorer
                return get_path_from_explorer(hwnd)
            case 'Progman':  # Desktop
                return get_path_from_desktop()
            case '#32770':  # File Dialog
                return get_path_from_file_dialog(hwnd)
            case _:
                return ''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    activator = Activator()
    activator.activate()


Key Components of the Code:

The Activator class listens for keyboard events, retrieves the active window, and prints the selected file path.

The get_path_from_explorer(), get_path_from_desktop(), and get_path_from_file_dialog() functions retrieve the file paths of selected items in File Explorer, the system desktop, and file dialogs respectively.


However, I'm not sure how to implement the get_path_from_file_dialog() function. I would appreciate any help from the community!
